# deviceready event not fired when app is restarted/resumed on android

Tags: android, cordova

If I use the back button when the history is empty or home button, my app closes. If I then start/resume the app, a call to document.addEventListener('deviceready', foo); will never cause foo to run.

According to the documentation, the call to addEventListener will in case of the device already being ready result in the event handler being called immediately.

That however seems to not be the case.

Why?

According to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html, addEventListener for deviceready should be called in the  handler, but such a handler will only be called once, when the app starts the first time.

Regardless if I was closing the app with the back button or the home button.

Comment: please use latest version of phonegap(cordova) 3.4 or 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"The Cordova deviceready event fires **once Cordova has fully loaded**. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function."*

I think you are searching for resume event! Otherwise you can encapsulate the eventhandler and  trigger it to the resume event listener

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button and home button in android and ios respectively to close the application. Application goes in background if you reopen the application, it switch from background to foreground.

- When application goes background "pause" event get fired.
- When application switch from background to foreground "resume" event
  get fired.

If you want again "deviceready" event get fired you should close/kill the application from recent and then open the application.